# Outlook web add-in activation rules in manifest

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am having trouble activating my add-in when a message is encrypted or signed.
It works fine on regular messages, but with encrypted or signed messages the button is just grayed out.

I have tried this without any luck:

```xml
<Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" ItemClass="IPM.Note.Secure" IncludeSubClasses="true" />
<Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" ItemClass="IPM.Note.Secure.Sign" IncludeSubClasses="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/read-scenario):

> Outlook doesn't activate add-ins in read form for certain types of messages, including items that are attachments to another message, items in the Outlook Drafts folder, or **items that are encrypted or protected in other ways**.

Answer (score 2):

Add-ins in Outlook are currently not supported on SMIME encrypted or signed messages. For support, please request this feature in [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins.)